# JQuery Datatables serialized data into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization, datatable

I'm really new at javascript and JQuery and I'm using JQuery datatables. I have read the page for 100 times and compared the html source and I managed to figure out how to pass the only checked fields into the sData array... Anyway...

I have this array:

```
var sData
```

which alerts me which rows I have selected when I submit the form, it gives something like this:

```
1=1&2=2&10=10&18=18
```

---

Before this I used simple table with each row a button which reserved me the one I choose, so this step is really confusing for me...

I used this query to add them to the database:

```
if (isset($_POST['addtolist']) ) 
{
    $itemid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemid']);
    $AddToListQuery = "
                    INSERT INTO
                    reservelist
                   (itemid, projectid)
                    VALUES
                   ('$itemid', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['projectidtoreserve']) . "')
                   ";      
    mysql_query($AddToListQuery, $conn);
    header('Location: pm_reserving.php');
    exit();
}
```

And it executed every time after clicking on a button at the specified table row.

But now I have no clue how to pass this sData array to the query...

I can't just use this `sData` like it now is to enter it into the database, because it wouldn't make any sense :/... What do I have to do with this sData?

**EDIT**
My JQuery code now:

```
        $('#form').submit( function() {
            var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
            alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );

        } );

        oTable = $('#table1').dataTable();
```

My form:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<button type=submit name=addtolist>Button</button>
```

When I submit the form, I receive the alert mentioned above (but now with id1=1&id2=2 etc.).

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['addtolist']) ) 
{
    $x=1;
    $values=array('+sData');
    while(isset($_POST['id'.$x]))
    {
        $values[$x-1]=$_POST['id'.$x];
        $AddToListQuery = "
                        INSERT INTO
                        reservelist
                       (itemid, projectid)
                        VALUES
                       ('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'.$x]) ."', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['projectidtoreserve']) . "')
                       ";
        $x++;
    }
    mysql_query($AddToListQuery, $conn);
    header('Location: pm_reserving.php');
    exit();
}
```

This PHP loop is probably a big fail...But I need this sData var to put into the PHP variable... Oh god I'm so lame at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are passing `sData` using GET or POST, the way to recover it is like this:

If the URL is (for example in GET): `www.url.com?key=value&key2=value2`

In PHP you read it as:

```
$value=$_GET['key'];  // if you used POST it's $value=$_POST['key'];
$value2=$_GET['key2'];
```

So in your example it would be:

```
$id1=$_GET['1'];
$id2=$_GET['2'];
....
```

As you can see it is not ideal, cause you need to know the id to read the id... a much better format for `sData` would be:

```
id1=1&id2=2&id3=10&id4=18
```

That you would read:

```
$id1=$_GET['id1']; //gets a 1
$id2=$_GET['id2']; //gets a 2
$id3=$_GET['id3']; //gets a 10
$id4=$_GET['id4']; //gets a 18
```

An easy way to read it would be:

```
$x=1;
$values=array();
while(isset($_GET['id'.x])){
     $values[$x-1]=$_GET['id'.x];
     $x++;
}

echo "Number of Ids=".($x-1);
print_r($values);
```

EDIT: How all this works if you are submining a form.

```
<form id="form" action="example.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="id2" name="id2" value="2" />
<button type=submit name=addtolist>Button</button>
```

If you just submit this, the variables `id1` and `id2` will be submited using POST to `example.php`. Now this PHP should do this:

example.php

```
$x=1;
$values=array();
while(isset($_POST['id'.x])){
     $values[$x-1]=$_POST['id'.x];
     $x++;
}

echo "Number of Ids=".($x-1);
print_r($values);
```

This will work even if you use more variables if they are all named id+number, where number keeps increasing by 1 in each new variable (id1, id2, id3, id4 ....)

After this the $values array cointains all the variables passed! you can use them in query or wherever you need.

Comment: Ok I did what you said about the ID1=1 etc. How can I pass this sData array into the $values array?

Comment: oh, you mean how to do pass from Jquery to a PHP file? that's a AJAX call. You basically need to trigger a event that will launch a javascript/Jquery function (for example a `onclick="something()"` in a button) then do a `$.post("example.php",{$("#Form").serialize()}, function(data){alert("OK");});`

Comment: Haha...im not sure. Edited my post maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: Ah you are just submithing a form! that works too, np! lemme edit my answer to explain how that works

Comment: Only ID1 gets confirmed atm

Comment: if you have firebug, or chrome development tools you can check exactly what variables and values are being passed by POST to the PHP. that would help. If that doesn't solve anything, try to get the values using only `$val1=$_POST['id1'];$val2=$_POST['id2']`. If that doesn't work either, there's a problem in the javascript part